# Scroll div horizontally and fixed the height of div

Tags: html, css

There are four images in the div, i want all images can be scrolled in same row, all images will not drop down to another row, how can i do this?

```
<style>
.more-product-images {
    height:90px;
    background-color:#000;
    width:1000px;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
</style>

<div class="more-product-images">
            <a href="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_product_full/public/45c857_a12aec4157fe68e01dc1d608627a4734.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox[0]" class="lightbox-processed"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_thumbnail/public/45c857_a12aec4157fe68e01dc1d608627a4734.jpg" width="120" height="92" alt="" title=""></a>
            <a href="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_product_full/public/45c857_b6f3583a3718298533f4f1f1ae58b690.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox[0]" class="lightbox-processed"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_thumbnail/public/45c857_b6f3583a3718298533f4f1f1ae58b690.jpg" width="120" height="92" alt="" title=""></a>
            <a href="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_product_full/public/45c857_db4093c431282a16ff3e80767b3f8ecc.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox[0]" class="lightbox-processed"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_thumbnail/public/45c857_db4093c431282a16ff3e80767b3f8ecc.jpg" width="120" height="92" alt="" title=""></a>
            <a href="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_product_full/public/45c857_df2173694b2e1cc56e443a4103f02ede.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox[0]" class="lightbox-processed"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_thumbnail/public/45c857_df2173694b2e1cc56e443a4103f02ede.jpg" width="120" height="92" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `.more-product-images a {float: left;}`.

Comment: check steps here http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the word scroll in title and description. Do you want a carousel effect? Sounds like you're looking for something like this 
http://flex.madebymufffin.com/examples/basic-carousel.html

```
<style>
.more-product-images {
height:90px;
background-color:#000;
width:1000px;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.boxes {width: 25%; display: flex-box;}
 </style>

<div class="more-product-images">
        <a           href="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_product_full/public/45c857_a12aec4157fe68e01dc1d608627a4734.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox[0]" class="lightbox-processed"><img class="boxes" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_thumbnail/public/45c857_a12aec4157fe68e01dc1d608627a4734.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
        <a href="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_product_full/public/45c857_b6f3583a3718298533f4f1f1ae58b690.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox[0]" class="lightbox-processed"><img class="boxes" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_thumbnail/public/45c857_b6f3583a3718298533f4f1f1ae58b690.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
        <a     href="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_product_full/public/45c857_db4093c431282a16ff3e80767b3f8ecc.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox[0]" class="lightbox-processed"><img class="boxes" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_thumbnail/public/45c857_db4093c431282a16ff3e80767b3f8ecc.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
        <a    href="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_product_full/public/45c857_df2173694b2e1cc56e443a4103f02ede.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox[0]" class="lightbox-processed"><img class="boxes" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/test/sites/default/files/styles/uc_thumbnail/public/45c857_df2173694b2e1cc56e443a4103f02ede.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex slider is pretty good. FYI you'll need to use javascript to do what you want to do. More specifically, as you begin working with javascript, look for tutorials on Jquery (a popular and easy to implement javascript library).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
.more-product-images img {
    float: left;
}
```

But here's a more detailed example: (I've made the anchor tags inline-blocks and removed the images for simplicity.

http://jsfiddle.net/f8Cd3/

I'd also recommend taking the width and height attributes off of the individual images and applying the width and height simply through css.

Comment: @hkinterview - See my amended answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **float: left** and is better pratice define the size by css.

```
.more-product-images img {
     width: 120px;
     height: 92px;
     float: left;
}
```

*Here is a code [using float:left](http://jsfiddle.net/YkRWD/)*

and maybe you should consider putting a margin between images like: **margin-left: 5px**

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` inside `lightbox-processed` class.